# Prove F is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ but F is not open in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

I am using Topology Without Tears by Morris

**Theorem**

If $F$ is non-empty countable subset of $\mathbb R$, prove $F$ is closed in $\mathbb R$
but $F$ is not open in $\mathbb R$

**My Best Effort to date**

*Part 1*

It suffices  to show that $\mathbb R\setminus F$ is open in $\mathbb R$

Since $F$ being countable and closed in $\mathbb R$,then $\mathbb R\setminus F $ is open and infinite
and $S=\{s_1…,s_n \}$

where $f:S\mapsto \mathbb N$ is a one-to-one correspondence and $s_n=f(n)$ $\forall n\in N$

So $\mathbb R\setminus  F$ is open and denumerable.

*Part 2*

Suppose X$\setminus$(1/n)${n \in N}$ is open then there is a point p such that (X$\setminus$(1\n)${ n\in N}$ -p ,X$\setminus$(1/n)$ {n\in N}$ +p)

But this means ((1/n)${n \in N}-p,(1/n){n \in N}+p)$$\notin$ A

So $p \notin A$ and is not open.

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: The set $(1/n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is not closed, since it does not contain the limit point $0$. Moreover, $\mathbb Q$ is neither closed nor open.

Comment: How can I show it without limit points. That is chapter 3

Comment: Show that $ X \setminus (1/n)_n$ is not open. In particular, show that there is no $ε>0$ such that $0 \in B(0,ε) \subset X \setminus (1/n)_n$.

Comment: If that’s supposed to be Nr. $6$ in Exercises $2.1$, you’ve misstated it. It should say: If $F$ is a non-empty countable subset of $\Bbb R$, prove that $F$ is not an open set, but that $F$ may or may not be a closed set depending on the choice of $F$.

Comment: Downvotes here could be that your question is not stated correctly in the question body (but it is correctly stated in the title) also it might help to use Mathjax

Comment: I corrected the question and stated it verbatim. I might have misunderstood the question

Comment: Can I be be upvoted a bit

Comment: At several places you wrote R/F and you probably meant R\F? It can be typeset as `$\mathbb R\setminus F$`, you'll get $\mathbb R\setminus F$.

Comment: I corrected it in the body. Now it’s uniform.can I be upvoted? Doing my best from drowning @Calvin Khor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to show every not empty open set of R is uncountable.
Thus F is not open.
If F = {0}, then F is closed.
If F = Q, then F is not closed.